# Nested ExternalProject_Add with shared dependencies

Tags: cmake, build-automation

I'm trying to apply `ExternalProject_Add` to automate the installation of dependencies of a mid sized C project. Things were going well until I had to install a library which uses `ExternalProject_Add` to install one of its dependencies, which also happen to be used by my own project. It would be nice if I could avoid having to rebuild this library, but instead use the already installed version.
Is there a good way to accomplish this? Can I tell ExternalProject to download stuff only if some condition, e.g., library already installed, is not met?

Comment: `Can I tell ExternalProject to download stuff only if some condition (e.g. library already installed) is not met?` Just check condition with `if` command and form parameters for `ExternalProject_Add` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I ended up setting a super build with CMake... Something similar to what is described in https://github.com/Sarcasm/cmake-superbuild. This way, I build my own project using external project, and am able to configure the dependencies between all targets. Also, I propagate the locations of already installed dependencies through ExternalProject's CMAKE_ARGS, in order to avoid rebuilding stuff. I can edit my question with more details about the final solution if anyone is interested..

Comment: `I can edit my question with more details about the final solution if anyone is interested.` - On Stack Overflow a question post shouldn't contain the solution. Instead, create answer and describe solution there. *Self-answering* is perfectly OK here.

Comment: Wow! That looks like the solution to all my problems! Thank you!